# How to transfer all outlook 365 emails to a safe place before leaving a company

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, backup, office365

In my current company, we use Office 365 service. I use Linux and access all my services through the web. Before leaving the company I need to have a complete backup of my emails, including all files, archived emails, sent emails, etc.

I need to be able to search the backup later and find files from it, etc.

How should I proceed?

I used Mozilla Thunderbird, but it only fetches emails from the inbox folder. I could not set it to download all emails.

Comment: Do you have permission from the owner of the company? If you do, then why won't they simply let your office365 account remain active after you've left the company?

Comment: Sorry, we cannot help with corporate IT issues. You'll have to ask your IT department.

Comment: @Gantendo I definitely have the permission. But then does the company have to pay for licenses of all past employees forever, if they want to keep their office365 accounts?

Comment: IANAL but... the emails you sent & received on company time while using their email account are probably the property of the company. It is easy to imagine what kinda problems having them can cause. But what good can come of you having them while the email account is no longer active and you are no longer an employee?

Comment: Tell the owner that if they want you to store the emails (and retrieve them upon request) they should pay you for that service. Make sure you get that agreement in black and white. Why work for free if you are no longer an employee? But it doesn't make sense for an owner of a company to make such a request to an ex-employee. They own the account, so they can retrieve the emails themselves if they want.

Comment: You could export the items to a .pst file that you can restore later as needed and use by importing if this action meet the company's compliance requirements. For more details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-your-email-e5845b0b-1aeb-424f-924c-aa1c33b18833

Comment: I appreciate your legal concerns, here's some context: I'm the tech lead of this small company. Things are changing fast and even after leaving I will be asked to help them for some time. For that kind of role in small companies, you do not expect to just say goodbye and never help them, well you can, but I don't. Now I won't count on the IT to remember to not delete this specific account: months ago they mistakenly deactivated a company sim I used for 2fa in many accounts and it cause a lot of trouble. "Sorry, your IT deleted everything and now I cannot help you" is not an option for me. :)